# How do I change the GDM login background in Fedora 22?

Tags: fedora

Has anyone figured out how to change the GDM login background in Fedora 22 yet? In Fedora 21 (and older versions), you did this by:

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme
make copy of "noise-texture.png" [gdm background]
copy "selected-background-image.png" to /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme
delete "noise-texture.png"
rename "selected-background-image.png" to "noise-texture.png"
```

When I do a 'sudo find / |grep noise-texture', I can only find /usr/share/gnome-control-center/pixmaps/noise-texture-light.png, and when I replace that, and log out, it still uses the grey background, not the custom image.

I've read that the login screen uses Wayland now, instead of X, however I have not been able to find any more details other than that, or if it's even accurate. Has anyone figured out how to do this for Fedora 22 yet?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/534187/where-is-the-login-screen-wallpaper-for-gdm-stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Gnome Shell 3.16 themes are stored as binary in a .gresource file.

You can tell it by the url of the noise-texture.png which is the GDM's default background at line 1607.

```
$ vi /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-classic.css

#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2e3436 url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
  background-repeat: repeat; }
```

In order to change the background you have to extract everything from /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource then recompile it.

You can find script sh to do this and complete details on ArchWiki, i'm not posting instructions here as I didn't test it and don't want to point eventually wrong informations.

source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Log-in_screen_background_image

Comment: Been looking for a response for this issue for quite a while. Many thanks!